# Docker icon on Windows 10 still starting

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, desktop-icons

I have a Docker for Windows 10 installed. It seems it is running I can see my images in docker panel can run docker commands in cli. But the docker icon in info panel on the bottom right show me the text **docker is starting**. Also I cant close contextual menu after right click on the icon. It is still open. Like on the picture below. What is wrong with that?

[image]

Comment: After the x restarts it starts to run correctly in some magic way.

Answer (score 1):

On my side I had a similar issue on my Windows 10 machine.

It was probably caused by a forced shutdown after sleep mode (perhaps no more battery).

I tried many things like restarting the Services but it was not working when I started to watch the folder `.docker` in my home directory.

I did this:

- I first stopped my Docker Desktop process
- then I deleted the file named `.token_seed.lock` in ${USER_HOME}/.docker/
- Start the Docker Desktop from the shortcut

and after that my Docker was running without any issue and my stored images were correctly displayed (and starting / stopping properly).